# Resizing frames in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been making a small program with the Tkinter module in python, and I was wondering whether it was possible or not to resize a frame in my program with the mouse. As in, the user can drag the frame border and it will resize itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your use of terminology makes the question unclear. Windows which may be resized by the user are called [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) windows. These are what appear as rectangular windows on the display, with a frame around them, typically a title bar, and edges or corners that can be grabbed and resized.

The term [Frame](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm) refers to a container widget that must be inside a Toplevel or one of its descendents. A Frame has the ability to be resized but you have to write the code to let you interactively resize them. For example, you could place a little grip widget in one or more corners, and writing bindings to the press, motion and release of a mouse button.

Depending on the effect you are looking for, you might want a [PanedWindow](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/panedwindow.htm) which is a container that includes a sash that lets you adjust the proportion of space between two other widgets.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the widget Frame. But your answer was still very helpful. I will investigate these 'panedwindow's a little more, but I'm quite certain that this is what I was looking for. Thank you!